# disable verification code being sent on email verification on cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

```
userPool.signUp(
                userData.email,
                userData.password,
                attributeList,
                [],
                async (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        failure(new HttpException(500, err.message));
                    }

                    let myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                        IdentityPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID!,
                    });
                    new AWS.Config({
                        credentials: myCredentials,
                        region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
                    });
                    let cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
                    cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminConfirmSignUp(
                        {
                            UserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID!,
                            Username: userData.email,
                        },
                        function (err, _data) {
                            if (err) {
                                failure(err);
                            }

                            cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminUpdateUserAttributes(
                                {
                                    UserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID!,
                                    Username: userData.email,
                                    UserAttributes: [
                                        {
                                            Name: 'email_verified',
                                            Value: 'true',
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                () => {
                                    console.log('done');
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    );

                    if (result) {
                        const cognitoUser = result.user;

                        success({ user: cognitoUser, sub: result.userSub });
                    } else {
                        failure(
                            new HttpException(
                                500,
                                'Authentication server error, please try again later'
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
```

This is the code by which I am signing up a user and auto verify that user on cognito.
Problem being I have 2 different set of user roles, and one user i am auto confirming but for the other i want them to manually confirm, using the code that is sent by cognito.

Now for the one type of user for which the auto_confirmation is done the email and cofirm user is working perfectly, with one caveat.
The code for verification is being sent even if it's auto verified by admincognito.

How can i disable this on this particualr set of code, so that the other user role can confirm with the code that is being sent via email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito isn't really configurable in this regard. Your escape hatch in this case is the lightly documented [custom email sender lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html). Perform whatever checks you want before sending the email through SES (or not).

Comment: Great idea. I'm working an app that uses SES, but not through Cognito. Evidently there's no way to prevent Cognito from sending email verification. Will be sending the verifications to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a pre-signup lambda trigger. And passing in the role to it as a user attribute and then auto verifying email and user based on the role.